Jboss Security Domains with EJB Scheduler does not find required security-domain
I am not so experienced with the JBoss, and have an issue getting an EJB Scheduler to run.
There is an application, where the client is authenticated with a client cert. Therefore the security domain is defined like:
<security-domains>
    ...
    <security-domain name="my-domain" default-realm="my-client-cert-realm" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
        <realm name="my-client-cert-realm" role-mapper="clientCertRole"/>
    </security-domain>
</security-domains>
<security-realms>
    ...
    <identity-realm name="my-client-cert-realm" identity="clientCertUser"/>
</security-realms>

Now I try to add a scheduler which runs a job like:
import javax.ejb.*;

@Singleton
public class MyScheduler {

  @Lock(LockType.READ)
  @Schedules({
    @Schedule(
        hour = "*",
        minute = "*",
        info = "Scheduled job.") })
  public void runJob() {
    // Run the job
  }
}

As soon as I try to start the jboss this combination leads to the error
09:35:40,526 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") fehlgeschlagen – Adresse: ([("deployment" => "my-app.war")]) – Fehlerbeschreibung: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Erforderliche Dienste, die nicht installiert sind:" => ["jboss.security.security-domain.my-domain"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Dienste mit fehlenden/unverfügbaren Abhängigkeiten" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"my-app.war\".component.MyScheduler.CREATE [jboss.security.security-domain.my-domain] fehlt"]
}

If I remove the security-domain from the jboss-web.xml then it works again
<jboss-web>
  <!--<security-domain>my-domain</security-domain>-->
  <context-root>app</context-root>
</jboss-web>

Any idea, why the security-domain is missing when creating the scheduler and how I could modify the configuration or code so it would work? Or maybe even another idea how to add the scheduler?

This looks like it's likely JBoss EAP 7.x. What specific version are you using?

Exactly, 7.4.15

That definitely seems odd. Could the resource be defined in a different profile? You could open a support case for this as well.

The problem was, that there needs to be an application-security-domain in ejb like
/subsystem=ejb3/application-security-domain=my-application-domain:add(security-domain="my-domain")

for this to work.(https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.3/html/developing_ejb_applications/ejb_application_security#configure_the_application_security_domain_using_the_management_cli)
